# how to create rounded ribbon effect in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have already done everything else (like shadow,gradient), but now I'm just stuck at one step.

How can I bend the rectangle (pointed with arrows) to get this rounded ribbon effect:

[image]

Comment: What's "everything" that you've already done? What's missing? Do you just need to bend the rectangle or add the second gradient (or both) or apply a dropshadow effect?

Comment: koiyu........:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think to create that shape you are to use the Pen Tool and just draw the custom shape:
[image: outline with Pen Tool]

And after that just add Gradients :
[image: gradients]

Comment: Ok, I've done this in Illustrator, as I like the Pen Tool better in Illustrator, but you can do the same thing in Photosop

Answer (score 4):

Like @[Flavius recommended](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/how-to-create-rounded-ribbon-effect-in-photoshop/3013#3013), the shape is best to be drawn as a vector. In his answer, he used the pen tool, but you could use the normal rectangle shape tool and then `warp` the shape.

After selecting the shape layer you want to modify (in this example the rectangle), choose `Edit` → `Transform [path]` → `Warp`. **Or** you could click on the `warp` button from the toolbar while you're `Free transforming` the layer:

[image: warp button]

Then you could either use (and modify) some pre-set warps…

[image: warp options]

… **or** just warp as you wish with the new warp handles your layer has:

[image: custom warping]

For the best quality it is recommended to use vector graphics (pen tool, paths, shapes, …), but you can use the warp tool with your raster graphics as well.